# Switching endianness on ARM

Tags: android, arm, cpu-architecture, endianness, processor

I have heard that ARM processors can switch between little-endian and big-endian. What do processors need this for? Is it used on Android phones?

Comment: Mostly a marketing checkbox.  there is a very very small list of products that are arm instruction set based that are big endian by default.  the big endian modes are not what you are thinking anyway, and they have instructions on the newer cores to deal with byteswapping.   getting the toolchain to work, etc is a PITA.

Comment: Intel had bought up DEC probably to crush the alpha but the side effect was the strongarm which became xscale which defaulted to big endian (product line now owned by Marvell).  Which at the time was word invariant (BE-32)(newer cores from arm are BE-8, byte invariant, you can have one or the other not both).  Very difficult at that time to get a toolchain to work(gnu/gcc), easier now despite BE-8 being more complicated.

Comment: The newer cores have an instruction that can switch modes and switch back so you can have a critical section. older cores its a global setting you pretty much want to make the whole system big endian.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the processor, it can be possible to switch endianness on the fly. Older processors will boot up in one endian state, and be expected to stay there. In the latter case, the whole design will generally be set up for either big or little endian.

The primary reason for supporting mixed-endian operation is to support networking stacks where the underlying datasets being manipulated are native big-endian. This is significant for switches/routers and mobile base-stations where the processor is running a well-defined software stack, rather than operating as a general purpose applications device.

Be aware that there are several different implementations of big-endian behaviour across the different ARM Architectures, and you need to check exactly how this works on any specific core.

Answer (score 1):

No processor **needs** to be run in big or little endianness. The reason for that is simple: anything you can do in one mode, you can also do in the other. That's of course generally true of any Turing complete computer, but in general CPU's have instructions to reverse the data within words.

In ARM it seems that this instruction is called the `rev` instruction. Let me [quote Peter Harris](https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/architectures-and-processors-forum/4901/how-to-set-endianness-in-arm-cortex-a8/26783#26783), a Mali GPU distinguished engineer at Arm:

> If you are going to do functions to load single fields from memory then just use little-endian loads and use [the "rev" instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/rev) to reverse the result - it's only one additional instruction and much faster (and small enough to be inlined so you avoid the function overhead too).

The `rev` instruction reverses the *bytes* in a word. Although instructions such as `rev` generally do not reverse the bits within a byte you can assume that the bit order is fixed (when debugging the bits in bytes are generally shown as big endian, e.g. when looking at the hexadecimal representation).

Beware that any number larger than that fits in a register should be handled correctly by the application; for instance the code for handling 128 bits do not just have to worry about the order of the bytes, but also of the 2 x 64 bit words.

Answer (score -4):

You can switch endianness, but you wouldn't do that after the OS is up and running.  It would only screw things up.  If you were going to do it, you'd do it very early on in the boot sequence.  By the time your app is running, the endianness is chosen and won't be changed.

Why would you do it?  The only real reason would be if you were writing embedded software that had to deal with a lot of little-endian data, or to run a program that was written assuming little endian and not fixed to be endian agnostic.  This kind of data tends to come from an x86 app that wrote things out in its native byte order (x86 is little endian).  There's not a lot of other reasons to do it.  You'll see ARM pretty much exclusively run in big endian mode.

Comment: arm is little endian, big endian on arm is the exception.

Comment: This is only correct for ARMv6 and maybe most ARMv7. In ARMv8, endian is dynamic (and only applied to the data side).

Comment: [This discussion on ARM community](https://community.arm.com/support-forums/f/architectures-and-processors-forum/4901/how-to-set-endianness-in-arm-cortex-a8) goes into it. If you want big endianness you generally run the code in privileged mode and you need to recompile the compiler itself. That basically means that you don't do it unless your processor has one specific function in a networking product (which is probably why it still exists). Gabe, maybe it is time to review and adjust your answer? I'm a big proponent of big endianness, but hey, denying reality is never a good idea.